# Multiply column values in SQL, then add all the values - Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel, sum, multiplication

I have this code:

```
DB::table('product_list')->select(DB::raw('(value*quantity) as total'))->get();
```

and this is my DB:

```
product = id,quantity,value,color
```

And I want them to be added all like:

```
1|10|500|blue
2|20|250|red
total for each = value*quantity
total = 10000
```

But it gives me:

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#266 (1) { ["total"]=> int(5000) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#263 (1) { ["total"]=> int(5000) } }
```

And the only way to sum it all is by running a foreach loop in PHP but I need to do it directly from the DB. But there must be another way, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SQL `SUM` function:

```
$total = DB::table('product_list')
           ->selectRaw('SUM(value * quantity) as total')
           ->pluck('total');
```

Comment: Hey, that `selectRaw` its a pretty good one, this is my final query:`DB::table('product_list')->selectRaw('SUM(value * quantity) as total')->pluck('total')`, for getting the total value directly, thanks.